# How to resolve 7-zip's 'Warnings: Headers Error' from .zip created by Ant build?

Tags: ant, zip, 7zip, antbuilder

I have code for creating zip file in ant build script.

```
<target name="zip-dist" description="archiving artifacts">
    <zip destfile="${artifacts}/${zipfile}.zip" update="false" basedir="${target.dist}" includes="*.xyz-*" />
</target>
```

When file is being extracted using win zip `right click -> Extract All...` there's no warning, but while extracting with `7-zip` showing **'Warnings: Headers Error'** but its successful.

I know this has no effect on the output as its just a warning so suggested users to *ignore* it or use *win-zip* method.

But trust me it is impossible to make them understand and ***they all are keep on eating my head***. 
There are many users and I am banging my head repeating same thing again and again. Still they want it to be fixed.

Can I use any attribute in `ant-zip` target or should I use any different zipping technique in `ant build`?

I have searched multiple online sources, this is last hope!
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue.
Fixed adding only one attribute, to force Zip64 extensions:

```
zip64Mode="always"
```

Try and should work for you too.

Comment: Could you please specify to which element you added this attribute?

Comment: @bugmenot123 it is a zip task attribute what else ;-) <zip zip64Mode="always" ..... />

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regular zip target used 7-zip to create zip.

```
<property name="7z.exe" value="C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe" />

<target name="zip-dist" description="archiving artifacts">
    <exec executable="${7z.exe}">
        <arg value="a" />
        <arg value="-tzip" />
        <arg value="${artifacts}/${zipfile}.zip" />
        <arg value="${target.dist}/*.xyz-*" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

As 7-zip includes all necessary information regarding header, so that warning will not occur.

Of course, 7-zip must be available in system.